# Angular Date Display from the Database onto the View in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, database, datetime, model-view-controller

I have an MVC application where i am getting data from the MVC Controller and pass it to View as JSON using angular. One of the data field is a datetime value. On the controller side the datefield is showing in the format {5/27/2019 12:00 AM) but when it is on the angular side the same date field is showing for example this: /Date(864511200000)/

I have tried convert /Date(864511200000)/ to  short date of {MM/dd/yyyy} using

```
 <td>{{employee.DateOfBirth | date:'shortDate'}}</td>
```

but it wont work. My controller method

```
    public JsonResult GetEmployees()
    {
        var employees= db.Employees.ToList();
        return Json(employees, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Angular code

```
myApp.controller('EmployeeCtrl',function ($scope, $http) {

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/Employees/GetEmployees'
    }).then(function (response) {
        $scope.employees= response.data;
        console.log(response.data);
    });
});
```

my View Code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
        <td>{{employee.DateOfBirth | date:'shortDate'}}</td>
```

//rest of the code

Answer (score 0):

You need to build own custom filter for date format. Here is my code will be help you in your scenario.

It is in the ISO 8601 string format.

```
app.filter('inputDate', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
        return function (input, format) {
           return (input) ? $filter('date')(input, format) : '';
        };
}]);
```